# How to remove numbers from a string

Tags: ruby, string

I want the following:

```
"Set off to London 29min"
```

to become:

```
"Set off to London min"
```

I also want to remove the `"min"` and space as well, but I know how to do it in a very inefficient way.

Comment: Your intention behind the last sentence is not clear. Does it mean that you do not need help with that part because you can do it, or are you looking for a more efficient way?

Comment: In the last part, it is not clear what you want to remove. Do you want the string `"min"` to be removed so that `"Hemingway"` becomes `"Hegway"`? What about `"The min max strategy in game theory"`? Should it become `"The the max strategy in game theory"`?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The title suggests you want to remove numbers from anywhere in a string. Your text suggest it's only in one place in a string. Which is it?

Answer (score 12):

This will do:

```
string.tr("0-9", "")
```

Comment: In case anyone arrives here wondering the opposite (remove characters, leaving just numbers), it's `string.tr("a-zA-Z", "")`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly then here are some solutions.

```
string = "Set off to London 29min"
string.gsub!(/\d+/,"")
#=> "Set off to London min"
```

or if you would also like the literal word 'min' taken out as well

```
string = "Set off to London 29min"
string.gsub!(/(\d+|(min))/,"")
#=> "Set off to London "
```

Comment: `string.gsub!(/\d+/,"")` will remove *all* numbers from the string. The OPs intention isn't clear so this could very likely not be what is desired.

Comment: I think we all understand that, why even comment? There is a reason I said "If I understand you correctly"

Comment: Why comment? Because I'm trying to help you create an answer that is more comprehensive. Since the OP's question isn't clear it's important to cover the bases and explain the upsides/downsides to the solutions. Answers can be minimal and leave the pitfalls for the asker to discover, or they can be educational and teach them. It's your choice what you want to create.